# DLL LoadLibrary function is returning error code 193 when loading msvcr100.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I'm assuming that my application is 32bit and that this is causing the error. In my solution's Configuration Manager the Active solution platform is set to x64. However my Project platform is set to Win32 and I'm unable to change it for some reason. Is this what is causing my problem? If so, how do I enable changing the project's platform to x64?  When I edit the platform and change it to x64 it just goes back to win32...

Comment: `msvcr100.dll` is from Visual Studio 2010. Unless you have the toolset for 2010 installed and are using it your application written in 2019 should not be using it. The compiler for Visual Studio 2019 is not compatible with compiled binaries from 2010. The binary compatibility across VS versions is here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160)

Comment: From the previous comment link: ***The Microsoft C++ (MSVC) compiler toolsets in Visual Studio 2013 and earlier don't guarantee binary compatibility across versions. You can't link object files, static libraries, dynamic libraries, and executables built by different versions. The ABIs, object formats, and runtime libraries are incompatible.***

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what replaces msvcr100.dll in VS2019? I'm kinda stuck with some legacy code that I'm trying fix. I ported the old code into VS2019. Not sure what was used to originally build it...

Comment: You will have to recompile the legacy code and make sure that all libraries used are compiled with VS2019.

Comment: ***Not sure what was used to originally build it*** Visual Studio 2010. `msvcr100.dll` is the runtime from that version.

Comment: I have already recompiled the legacy code into an exe. In the code it looks for that particular library to load. I'm assuming that I need to change that code to look for another library to load although I'm not sure what is now required. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: It does make sense. ***In the code it looks for that particular library to load.*** If it is looking for `msvcr100.dll` it means there is still some VS2010 dependency that you need to remove. Are you linking to any third party libraries? If so did you rebuild all of these with VS2019? The code must not use any binaries created with VS 2010 otherwise it likely will not work.

Comment: I'm linking with jvm.dll. This dll came with the Java JRE. Part of what the code does is launch some Java processes. I'm not aware of any dll I need to rebuild. I assumed that I would need to add some redistributables from VS to the target system? Having said that, the JRE also provides vcruntime140.dll so I'm not sure what I need.

Comment: Actually, upgrading the C++ project should recompile the old version of the code step by step, including the dll. I suggest you could refer to the Microsoft Docs about [Upgrade C++ projects from earlier versions of Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/upgrading-projects-from-earlier-versions-of-visual-cpp?view=msvc-160).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there was some sort of corruption in my project. I created an empty solution and added an empty project. I noticed that the project allowed me to select x64 as my platform. I went over to my old project with the intent of moving my stuff over when I noticed that I could now select x64 as the platform on this project too. You gotta just bang your head against the wall at some of these issues we run into as software developers...  Thanks for all the help. It did help me narrow my focus.